# Automation Solution for both Web and WPF Applications

Tags: wpf, testing, selenium, automation, desktop

I wonder if someone has tackled the following challenge:

Automation Testing of a product which consist of both Web Application and WPF desktop application.
I'm looking for an automation solution which cover both under the same hood and technology.

for example: I thought of:  Selenium + MS UI Automation libraries both under the same automation project by using C# and .NET.

is it possible? are there any other solutions for this type of product?

I know QTP might do it, but lack of good browser support - by far not as good as Selenium.
and also lack of solid programming language like JAVA or C#.

appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I have heard that http://www.testplant.com/ can do this, but have never used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to use Selenium (C#) with MS UI Automation.  There would not be much in common besides code that you write yourself, but personally I think that this approach is a good idea if you are a strong programmer.  MS UI Automation is not easy at all.  An alternative would be to consider Silk4Net.  You could use it for web and WCF, but if you wanted to use Selenium for web and Silk4Net for WCF, that would work.  Just the plain ole Silk4Net 'library usuage' license is reasonably priced.

Comment: thanks. we want to try to keep it free :) so combining selenium and MS UI Automation is probably the way to go here.

Comment: yeah, i always want to keep it free, too :)